# to change selected value in combobox2 based on php variable as id of combobox1(need to do inside a loop)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working with a code in php. I planned to change a combobox2 selected value based on value selected in combobox1, but i need to do this inside a loop. that is, these two combo boxes are inside a loop that need to execute three times. so, totally six combo boxes will be displayed. I dont know how to explain my question exactly, but i am sure while looking my code what i worked will explain you clearly.
my code what i have tried is not giving me the output i want.
briefly, consider 3 rows of combo boxes, i need to change the combobox2 value in first row based on selection of combobox1 in that row and so on.
Here is the code what i tried.

```
<?php
        for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
        echo <<< EOT      //combobox1
                    <td><select name="$i" id=$i onChange="change1()">
                    <option selected="true" value="" style="display:none;">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="S">S</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="U">U</option>
                    </select></td>
        EOT;
                    $ia=$i."a";
                    echo <<< EOT    //combobox2
                    <td><select name="$ia" id=$ia>
                    <option selected="true" value="" style="display:none;">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="PASS">PASS</option>
                    <option value="RA">RA</option>
                    <option value="AB">AB</option>
                    </select></td></tr>
        EOT;
     ?>
        <script type=text/javascript>
           function change1(){
                 if (document.getElementById(<?php $i ?>).value !="U") {
                        document.getElementById(<?php $ia?>).value="PASS";
                   }
                    else{
                   document.getElementById(<?php $ia?>).value="";
               }

           }
        </script>
      <?php  }?>
```

actually i am not getting any error ... i assigned $i as id to combobox1 that is 1 for first row, 2 for second row and 3 for third row comboboxes.. but i tried printing like `alert(<?php echo $i ?>);` inside function change1 but it displays only '3' all the time ,that is last assigned value.. that was the problem

Comment: Remove all spaces **before** and/or after `EOT;` - There should **not** be any spaces surrounding it. That alone will produce an error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually i am not getting any error ... i assigned $i as id to combobox1 that is 1 for first row, 2 for second row and 3 for third row comboboxes.. but i tried printing like `alert(<?php echo $i ?>);` inside function change1 but it displays only '3' all the time ,that is last assigned value.. that was the problem

Comment: Error reporting may not be set/on, nor are you checking for them. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i am not getting any error msg even after adding the error reporting